# Hive Delimiter using :

Tags: sql, regex, string, hiveql, delimiter

I want to extract a column A that has values such as `W:X:Y:Z`. 
I am interested to extract Z from Column A. 
I tried multiple commands such as    `SPLIT(Table.A, "[:]"[3] )` but get an error.
What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Split function returns array. Array index `[3]` should be applied to the split function result:

```
with yourtable as ( -- use your table instead of this
select 'W:X:Y:Z' as A
)

select split(A,'\\:')[3] from yourtable;
```

Result:

```
Z
```